# Github CICD testing not working properly in laravel?

Tags: laravel, testing, github-actions

So I have created a set of github actions which intend to run a laravel. My intention is that everytime the user makes a push request then it will run the tests simultaneously, when the push is made. However whenever I push and it gets to the point where it runs the tests it says,

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: insert into `users`
```

Even though in my IDE code if I run PHP artisan test the tests run perfectly. Here is what my Github actions look like,

```
    on:
  push
jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

#change develop branch
    steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: '8.0'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: install dependencies
      run: composer install --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-suggest --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - name: install doctrine
      run: composer require doctrine/dbal
    - name: Generate Key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Directory Permssions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Create Database
      run: |
        mkdir -p database
        touch database/database.sqlite
    - name: Execute Tests (unit and feature testing)
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: sqlite
        DB_DATABASE: database/database.sqlite
        DB_USERNAME: root
        DB_HOST: localhost
        DB_PORT: 3306
      run: php artisan migrate
    - name: test
      run: php artisan test
```

I have run this without the database username, host or port.

Answer (score 0):

You are specify `env` DB params for migrate step (which is marked 'Execute Tests (unit and feature testing)' for some reason), and not specify it for `test`, so it seems to use invalid defaults.